# Dynamically adding post titles to a list in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

UPDATE:
I've managed to get it working, but there are a couple of additions that I'm trying to work out without much luck,

I'm using the below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("ul.activities_list").append(jQuery.cookie("listItem"), {
                expires: 365,
                path: '/'
            }); //<---end of $.cookie);
  jQuery(".activity").on("click", ".add_activity", function() {

   // jQuery(".add_activity").live('click',function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.title').html();

        // Add activity item to the panel list.
        jQuery("ul.activities_list").prepend(jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button id="remove_item" class="button is-primary is-white">Remove</button></li>'));

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", ((jQuery.cookie("listItem") ? jQuery.cookie("listItem") : '') + jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button id="remove_item" class="button is-primary is-white">Remove</button></li></li>').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html()));
    });
    jQuery("#remove_item").live('click',function () {

        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        var removed_item = jQuery('.activities_list').html();

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", removed_item);
    });
});
```

But it isn't saving/updating the cookie sitewide (even though I have set a path to '/'.

Also, these values are being sent in a form via a hidden field. Is there a way to remove the li and a tags, so that +title+ is only stored in an array?

I have a staging site on  https://wincstudio.co.uk/henqueens

———

PREVIOUS

I have a list of posts on a page with a button to add each post to a list in jQuery.

The user should be able to remove an item from the populated list and a cookie should save the list so it doesn't disappear on refresh.

I've tried a few bits of code from here which only pull in the first posts. So I am trying to start again, but not having much luck.

```
//php

<ul class="activities">
  <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 5 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li class="activity">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<button type="submit" class="add" id="add_activity">Add Activity</button>

</li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>

///panel

<ul class="activities_list">
  <li>When button#add_activity is clicked to appear  here<button>Remove</button></li>
  <li>Activity <button>Remove</button></li>
  <li>Activity <button>Remove</button></li>
</ul>


//jQuery

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.activities").append($.cookie("listItem"));
    $("#add_activity").click(function () {
        $('ul.activities').prepend($('<li>List Item</li>');

        $.cookie("listItem", (($.cookie("listItem") ? $.cookie("listItem") : '') + newLi.clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html()));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated  your code you can check it. Before checking please remove cookies related to it.

```
<ul class="activities">
  <?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'page','numberposts' => 5, 'order'=>'ASC' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
<li class="activity">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<button type="submit" class="add add_activity" id="add_activity">Add Activity</button>

</li>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>

<ul class="activities_list">

</ul>

<script>
//jQuery

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("ul.activities_list").append(jQuery.cookie("listItem"));
    jQuery(".add_activity").click(function () {
        var title = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').html();
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().next('ul').prepend(jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button class="remove_item">Remove</button></li>'));

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", ((jQuery.cookie("listItem") ? jQuery.cookie("listItem") : '') + jQuery('<li>'+title+'<button class="remove_item">Remove</button></li></li>').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html()));
    });
    jQuery(".remove_item").live('click',function () {

        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        var removed_item = jQuery('.activities_list').html();

        jQuery.cookie("listItem", removed_item);
    });
});
   </script>
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much. Would it be possible for the appended list to be shown automatically without refreshing the page? Just the opposite of removing them?

Comment: @PaddyWinsley this code update the list without refreshing. May be you are missing something while putting it in your code. Can you check my whole code separately?

Comment: Thanks IncipoentInfo, I've updated the code to the attached which is nearly doing what I need ```